# Displaying a file in a TextArea

Tags: java

So I have created a GUI and have to open a file using JFileChooser and display the file in a textArea that I have also created. My issue is that the textArea was created in a different class. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel{

JButton btnOpen = new JButton("Open");
private ObjectOutputStream output;


public ButtonPanel() {
ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();

add(btnOpen);
btnOpen.addActionListener(handler);
}//end constructor


private void openFile() {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);

    String fileName;

    fileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

    try {

        output = new ObjectOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath())));

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There was a problem opening this file", "Error opening file", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }



}//end openFile



private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource()== btnOpen) {

            openFile();

        }

    }//end actionPerformed



}//end actionlistener



}//end class
```

Now here is the class that contains the textArea:
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class OutputPanel extends JPanel{

public OutputPanel() {

JTextArea txtOutput = new JTextArea(20,50);
add(txtOutput);
}


   }//end class
```

I have tried many solutions however none of them have worked mainly because the textArea is in a separate class. For example, if the textArea was in the same class I could simply just do " txtOuput.setText but because it is in a separate class, it does not like it. So main question is, how to get the file I choose from the JFileChooser to display in the textArea? It could be something very simple that I am overlooking however, I have spent hours trying to figure this out. Hopefully this gives enough detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a has-a relationship ButtonPanel and OutputPanel?

```
private OutputPanel myOutputPanel;

public ButtonPanel(OutputPanel op) {
    ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();

    myOutputPanel = op;

    add(btnOpen);
    btnOpen.addActionListener(handler);
}//end constructor
```

Then add a getter method in OutputPanel and access the JTextArea as needed:

```
myOutputPanel.getTxtOutput().setText("ABC");
```